# How can I force all compile dependencies to be declared in the Maven POM?

Tags: maven

Sometimes our developers use classes that are not directly defined as `compile` dependencies in the POM. They rather depend on an artifact (again scope `compile`) which in turn has a transitive `compile` dependency to the artifact that contains the used class.

Like this:

- A uses classes of B and C
- A depends on B, but not C
- B depends on C

Is there any way I can check this during the Maven build (except for dependency reports etc.) or even force that all compile dependencies must be declared directly in the project's POM?

Comment: have you tried google first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enforce, during the build, that dependencies are correctly declared, just use the [dependency:analyze-only](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html) mojo.

You can see a good example here: http://www.stuartgunter.org/minimally-complete-dependency-declaration-maven/